# What is the "HORI Deluxe Wheel Attachment Mario" product for?

Tags: nintendo-switch, mario-kart-8-deluxe, gaming-accessories

I ordered *HORI Deluxe Wheel Attachment Mario* a little quickly and without thinking.

[image]

What is the added value of this product? The steering wheel can be rotated, but the rotation is not recognized. You still have to operate the Joy-Con, it seems like a product just for looks?

I quickly put it away in the basement because I don't see the benefit. Do I operate / use it wrong?

Comment: Its benefits appear to be "more realistic control and better grip" based on what the marketing materials indicate. Reviews do indicate that you can steer with it -- are you sure yours isn't a knockoff?

Comment: You have turned turned on tilt controls, right?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> The steering wheel can be rotated, **but the rotation is not recognized**.

It seems like you haven't turned on tilt controls.

[How to Activate/Deactivate Tilt Controls](https://www.nintendo.co.uk/Support/Nintendo-Switch/How-to-Activate-Deactivate-Tilt-Controls-Mario-Kart-8-Deluxe--1518482.html) (from Nintendo's support):

1. From the main menu, select the game mode you want to play (Single Player, Multiplayer, Online Play or Wireless Play).
2. Set up the race until you reach the point where you select a car. (This is right after you've selected your character.)
3. On the car selection screen, press the + Button or - Button to display the car's stats. The icon in the top centre of the stat window is for tilt controls. You can also reach this option during a race by pressing the + or - Button.
4. Press the button shown next to the tilt controls icon to toggle this feature on or off. A yellow curved arrow will appear over the icon when the feature is on.

---

As for the purpose of the product itself: it basically serves as a larger base to hold onto while using tilt controls, since it can be hard and painful with larger hands.